# Login Screen Not Appearing on External Monitor in Clamshell Mode

Tags: display, macos, sleep-wake, login, closed-clamshell

When in clamshell mode, locked, and with display asleep, I expect to be able to wake the display and see the login screen on my external monitor by moving the mouse or typing. Instead, the screen stays dark while I enter my password and hit enter--and for many seconds after that if and only if I successfully login. This is not the end of the world, but without feedback I can spend a minute before I figure out the computer is actually off, or that I've been typing my password into an email I was working on before I stepped away since the display can sleep before locking me out.

I think this is happening because my Mac--even in clamshell mode--is not sending the login screen to the external monitor. Does anyone know a way to ensure the login screen appears on the external monitor? I would think I would do that by mirroring in the arrangement tab of the display preferences, but it's not available to me in clamshell mode.

My question is similar to this one, but there are a few differences, e.g., I'm running El Capitan:
[Change main desktop to external screen after sleep mode](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/118885/change-main-desktop-to-external-screen-after-sleep-mode)

rMBP, El Capitan, Acer B326HK